# how to pass current row into a oracle user defined function

Tags: oracle11g

I want to create an inline oracle function which will refer the column values of the current row being fetched and to return a value as per my conditions. I tried the same by passing ROWID into function and in the function body current row will be fetched using ROWID and manipulate the values.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CHECK_STATUS(P_ROWID) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   V_ROW MY_TBL%TYPE
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO V_ROW FROM MY_TBL WHERE ROWID=P_ROWID;
   IF V_ROW.COL1 IS NOT NULL AND
       V_ROW.COL2 IS NOT NULL AND 
       V_ROW.COL3 IS NOT NULL THEN

       RETURN 'OK';
   ELSE
      RETURN 'INCOMPLETE';
   END IF;
END;
```

This function is further called at various places as

```
SELECT A.*,CHECK_STATUS(ROWID) FROM MY_TBL A;
```

it works but slows down the query badly over a thousand records because on each fetch of rows function will again do a select query for getting the column values. I know that this can also be done as

```
   CREATE FUNCTION CHECK_STATUS(COL1,COL2,COL3) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
```

here the problem is that i want to nearly check 9 column values in the function and it looks odd to write the column name during every call of the function. I doubt is there any method that the function can refer the current row being fetched without receiving ROWID/ COLUMNS through parameter something like (THIS.COL1,THIS.COL2,THIS.COL3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [virtual column](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#BABIJABG) for this, using a case expression, and not have a function at all:

```
alter table my_tbl add (status generated always as
  (case when column1 is null or column2 is null or column3 is null
    -- etc., all 9 columns or whatever else you want to check
    then 'INCOMPLETE' else 'OK' end) virtual);
```

You can then query it with:

```
select column1, column2, ..., status from my_tbl
```

You can also add an index on the virtual column if that's useful for how you'll use it.

You could still use a (deterministic) function if you wanted to, with all the column values passed in - the 'looks odd' part would be hidden in the DDL, so queries wouldn't see it. It doesn't sound like using a function would add much in this case though.

Comment: thanks... you are right ... the very purpose of virtual column .... didnt think about because we just shifted from 10g to 11g..  will try soon..